# Android: database sqLite don't insert into table

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

Im trying to insert data into data base, but after adding ,when i check the data base i get a null result,it meas it still empty. I did not get where is the error ,i did some logs but i did not see the error.I'm sure i did a stupid error ,but i can't see it.
This insert is not working :
    bdd.insert(TABLE_RSSI, null, values)

PS:I did some changes in this code like ather name for colons ,and i add two clauns ,but before the code was perfectly running.
**this the code i'm using:**

```
public class MaBaseSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String TABLE_RSSI = "table_rssi";
private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
private static final String COL_X = "Xcoordinate ";
private static final String COL_Y = "Ycoordinate ";
private static final String COL_SSID = "SSID";
private static final String COL_RSSI = "RSSI";

private static final String CREATE_BDD = " CREATE TABLE " + " TABLE_RSSI " + " ("   + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_X + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_Y + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_SSID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_RSSI + " TEXT NOT NULL);";  


public MaBaseSQLite(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);
    Log.i("base créee","base créee");

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE" +  TABLE_RSSI + ";");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

```
public class GrillePuissanceBDD {

private static final int VERSION_BDD = 1;
private static final String NOM_BDD = "puissancesOffLine.db";
private static final String TABLE_RSSI = "table_rssi";
private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
private static final int NUM_COL_ID = 0;
private static final String COL_X = "Xcoordinate ";
private static final int NUM_COL_X = 1;
private static final String COL_Y = "Ycoordinate";
private static final int NUM_COL_Y = 2;
private static final String COL_SSID = "SSID";
private static final int NUM_COL_SSID = 3;
private static final String COL_RSSI = "RSSI";
private static final int NUM_COL_RSSI = 4;
private SQLiteDatabase bdd;
private MaBaseSQLite mabaseSQLite;

public GrillePuissanceBDD (Context context)

{ mabaseSQLite = new MaBaseSQLite (context , NOM_BDD ,null ,VERSION_BDD); 
Log.i("creation base","creation");
}

public void open()
{
    bdd = mabaseSQLite.getWritableDatabase();
}
 public void close()
 {
     bdd.close();
 }
public SQLiteDatabase getBDD()
{
    return bdd;
}
 public long insertGrille(Grille grille)
 {
     ContentValues values = new  ContentValues();
     //values.put(COL_ID, grille.getId());
     values.put(COL_X, grille.getxCoordinate());
     values.put(COL_Y, grille.getyCoordinate());
     values.put(COL_SSID, grille.getSsid());
     values.put(COL_RSSI, grille.getrssi());
     Log.i("insertion", values+"");
     Log.i("insertion",grille.getxCoordinate() +"");
     Log.i("insertion",bdd.insert(TABLE_RSSI, null, values) +"");
     return bdd.insert(TABLE_RSSI, null, values);


 }

 public int updateGrille (int id ,Grille grille)
 { ContentValues values = new  ContentValues();
 //values.put(COL_ID, grille.getId());
 values.put(COL_X, grille.getxCoordinate());
 values.put(COL_Y, grille.getyCoordinate());
 values.put(COL_SSID, grille.getSsid());
 values.put(COL_RSSI, grille.getrssi());
 return bdd.update(TABLE_RSSI, values,COL_ID + " = " +id, null );

 }

 public int removeLivreWithID (int id)
 {

     return bdd.delete(TABLE_RSSI, COL_ID + " = " +id ,null);
 }

 public Grille getGrilleWithTitre (String titre)
 {
    //Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_LIVRES, new String [] { COL_ID, COL_ISBN, COL_TITRE}, COL_TITRE + " LIKE \"" + titre + "\"", null, null, null, null);
    // Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_LIVRES, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_ISBN, COL_TITRE}, COL_TITRE + " LIKE \"" + titre +"\"", null, null, null, null);
     Cursor c =bdd.query(TABLE_RSSI, new String[] {COL_X, COL_Y,COL_SSID,COL_RSSI}, COL_ID + " LIKE '" + titre +"'", null, null, null, null);
     Log.i("getGrilleWithTitre",titre);
     Log.i("Cursor",cursorToPuissance(c)+"");
     return  cursorToPuissance(c);
 }

private Grille cursorToPuissance(Cursor c) {

    if (c.getCount()==0)
        {Log.i("c.getCount()",c.getCount()+"");
        return null;
        }
    c.moveToFirst();
    Grille grille = new Grille();
    grille.setId(c.getInt(NUM_COL_ID));
    grille.setxCoordinate(c.getString(NUM_COL_X));
    grille.setyCoordinate(c.getString(NUM_COL_Y));
    grille.setSsid(c.getString(NUM_COL_SSID));
    grille.setrssi(c.getString(NUM_COL_RSSI));
    Log.i("c.getString(NUM_COL_RSSI)",c.getString(NUM_COL_RSSI)+"");
    c.close();
    return grille;
}
```

}

```
public class Grille{
    private int id;
    private String xCoordinate;
    private String yCoordinate;
    private String ssid;
    private String rssi;
    public Grille ()
    {

    }
    public Grille(String xCoordinate, String yCoordinate,String rssi, String ssid )
    {
    this.ssid = ssid;
    this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate ;
    this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate ;
    this.rssi = rssi ;
}
public int getId()
{
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSsid()
{
    return ssid;
}

public void setSsid(String ssid)
{
    this.ssid = ssid;
}
public String getxCoordinate()
{
    return xCoordinate;
}
public void setxCoordinate(String xCoordinate)
{
    this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
}
public String getyCoordinate()
{
    return yCoordinate;
}
public void setyCoordinate(String yCoordinate)
{
    this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
}
public String getrssi()
{
    return rssi;
}
public void setrssi(String rssi)
{
    this.rssi = rssi;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "ID :"+id+"\nSSID : "+ssid+"\nX : "+xCoordinate+"\nY : "+yCoordinate+"\nPuissance : "+rssi ;
}
}
public class Add extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);


}

public void Ajouter(View view)
{
      EditText edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)  ;
      String xCoordinate = edittext1.getText().toString();
      EditText edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)  ;
      String yCoordinate = edittext2.getText().toString();
      EditText edittext3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3)  ;
      String ssid = edittext3.getText().toString();
      EditText edittext4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4)  ;
      String rssi = edittext4.getText().toString();
      xCoordinate = "xCoordinate";
      yCoordinate = "yCoordinate";
      ssid = "ssid";
      rssi = "rssi";
      switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.button1 :
            Grille grille = new Grille (xCoordinate,yCoordinate,ssid,rssi);

            //livre.setIsbn(isbn);
            //livre.setTitre(titre);
            GrillePuissanceBDD liv = new GrillePuissanceBDD(getApplicationContext());
            liv.open();
            liv.insertGrille(grille);
            Log.i("grille***",grille +"");
            Log.i("getxCoordinate***",grille.getxCoordinate() +"");
            Grille livreFromBdd = liv.getGrilleWithTitre(grille.getxCoordinate());
            Log.i("livreFromBdd",livreFromBdd +"");
            if(livreFromBdd != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, livreFromBdd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else 
            {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Prbleme", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            liv.close();
            break;
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And this the log :

```
04-16 03:46:35.660: I/creation base(814): creation
04-16 03:46:35.730: I/insertion(814): Ycoordinate=yCoordinate RSSI=ssid Xcoordinate =xCoordinate SSID=rssi
04-16 03:46:35.730: I/insertion(814): xCoordinate
04-16 03:46:35.750: I/insertion(814): 3
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): ID :0
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): SSID : rssi
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): X : xCoordinate
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): Y : yCoordinate
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): Puissance : ssid
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/getxCoordinate***(814): xCoordinate
04-16 03:46:35.820: I/getGrilleWithTitre(814): xCoordinate
04-16 03:46:35.820: I/c.getCount()(814): 0
04-16 03:46:35.820: I/Cursor(814): null
04-16 03:46:35.830: I/c.getCount()(814): 0
04-16 03:46:35.830: I/livreFromBdd(814): null
```

Thank you.

Comment: What object exactly is null if you check the database?

Comment: a edded those line to check in the add class : Grille livreFromBdd = liv.getGrilleWithTitre(grille.getxCoordinate()); , and it's declaration in GrillePuissnceBDD class is :public Grille getGrilleWithTitre (String titre) ==>i added the LOG
     {
     
      Cursor c =bdd.query(TABLE_RSSI, new String[] {COL_X, COL_Y,COL_SSID,COL_RSSI}, COL_ID + " LIKE '" + titre +"'", null, null, null, null);
      Log.i("Cursor",cursorToPuissance(c)+"");
      return  cursorToPuissance(c);
     }

Comment: to check if the data is inserted, do a rawQuery on the table first. `Cursor cursorTest = bdd.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_RSSI);` - if you get a result here, your are doing something wrong while selecting the data.

Comment: I tryed your code and i get this result :  `04-16 03:55:30.070: I/cursorTest(935): ID :1
04-16 03:55:30.070: I/cursorTest(935): SSID : 
04-16 03:55:30.070: I/cursorTest(935): X : 
04-16 03:55:30.070: I/cursorTest(935): Y : 
04-16 03:55:30.070: I/cursorTest(935): Puissance :`

Comment: you are inserting null values

Comment: i'm iserting the manually ,as you can see the contructor : Grille ,and i looged it : `04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): ID :0
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): SSID : rssi
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): X : xCoordinate
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): Y : yCoordinate
04-16 03:46:35.801: I/grille***(814): Puissance : ssid`